# Inject array of same interface type to class constructor

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following class that get IPersonOrderingStrategy[]:

```
public class PersonCollection : IPersonCollection
    {
        private IDictionary<int, IPerson> _persons;
        private IPerson _maxOrMinPerson;
        private readonly IPersonOrderingStrategy[] _personOrderingStrategies;

        private string _propertyName { get; set; }
        private string _maxMinOrdering { get; set; }

        public PersonCollection(IPersonOrderingStrategy[] personOrderingStrategies)
        {
            _persons = new Dictionary<int, IPerson>();
            _personOrderingStrategies = personOrderingStrategies;
        }
```

and I register all class:

```
public void ConfigureServices()
        {
            _serviceColletcion.AddTransient<IPerson, Person>();
            _serviceColletcion.AddTransient<IPersonCollection, PersonCollection>();
            _serviceColletcion.AddTransient<IPersonOrderingStrategy, MaximumPersonsOrdering>();
            _serviceColletcion.AddTransient<IPersonOrderingStrategy, MaximumPersonsOrdering>();
            _serviceColletcion.AddTransient<IPersonFactory, PersonFactory>();
            _serviceProvider = _serviceColletcion.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

while I'm coming to resolve the IPersonCollection:

```
        {
            var personCollection = _applicationServices.Resolve<IPersonCollection>();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:
Unable to resolve service for type 'Model.Person.IPersonOrderingStrategy[]' while attempting to activate 'BusinessComponent.Person.PersonCollection

my resolver looks like this:

```
public T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return (T)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
        }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your are using `Microsoft.Extensions.DepencyInjection`.

The support for injection of all implementations of `T` uses `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `T[]`. This is a design choice of the DI library.

Change your constructor to

```
public PersonCollection(IEnumerable<IPersonOrderingStrategy> personOrderingStrategies)
{
    _persons = new Dictionary<int, IPerson>();
    _personOrderingStrategies = personOrderingStrategies.ToArray();
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-registration-methods